# formGroup.getRawValue() throws error in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-library

When adding a FormControl to a FormGroup inside my own library, formGroup.getRawValue() gots error.

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup
} from '@angular/forms';
import {testfunc} from 'test-lib';                  // import a function from my own library.

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    const jsonA = {
      a: 'test',
      b: 10,
    };

    const fg = this.formBuilder.group(jsonA);       

    testfunc(fg);                                   // Add a Form Control inside this function

    const jsonB = fg.getRawValue();                 // 'control.getRawValue is not a function' error

  }
}
```

`test-lib` is a Angular library project build like [this post](https://willtaylor.blog/complete-guide-to-angular-libraries/). And the code for `testfunc` is as below.

```
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup
} from '@angular/forms';

export function testfunc(fg: FormGroup) {
  fg.addControl('c', new FormControl('newcontrol'));
}
```

`fg.getRawValue()` throws the error as below.

```
ERROR TypeError: control.getRawValue is not a function
    at forms.js:5460
    at forms.js:5582
    at forms.js:5508
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormGroup._forEachChild (forms.js:5504)
    at FormGroup._reduceChildren (forms.js:5576)
    at FormGroup.getRawValue (forms.js:5453)
    at AppComponent.ngOnInit (app.component.ts:34)
            :
```

When `testfunc` is in the same project with `AppComponent`, I do not see this error. But when the function is in the external library, I got this error.

Why I got this error when the `testfunc` is in the external library?

Angular version is 9.1.11.

Comment: FormGroup has getRawValue. FormBuilder doesn't. Check Angular documentation once. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

Comment: @AyushWalia fg is a FormGroup. this has getRawValue method.